# Logback AsyncAppender not writing logs to underlying appenders

Tags: logback, logback-classic

In logback.xml of my application I have an AsyncAppender defined as below.

```
<appender name="socketAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender">
    <param name="RemoteHost" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <param name="Port" value="15000" />
    <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="10" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
</appender>
<appender name="appLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/myApp.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/myApp.%d{yyyyMMdd.HH}00.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}][%p][%c{0}] %m%n]</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="AsyncLog" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="appLog" />
    <appender-ref ref="socketAppender" />
</appender>
```

When I deploy the war in Tomcat on Windows 10.

1. The log server listening on port 15000 wasn't receiving logs.
2. So I moved up the socketAppender to first position like below.

```
<appender name="AsyncLog" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="socketAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="appLog" />
</appender>
```

With this change log server started receiving logs, but the log file stopped writing/appending.
3) I also tried setting the queueSize and discardingThreshold properties on the appender, to no avail.

```
<discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
<queueSize>500</queueSize>
```

Can any logback experts please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Are there any other properties of AsyncAppender that may help fix this behaviour?

Comment: Tomcat version is 9.0.30.

Answer (score 3):

A colleague pointed me to this method in the class [ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/AsyncAppenderBase.java). AsyncAppender can attach only one appender and ignores any more appenders added beyond that.

```
public void addAppender(Appender<E> newAppender) {
        if (appenderCount == 0) {
            appenderCount++;
            addInfo("Attaching appender named [" + newAppender.getName() + "] to AsyncAppender.");
            aai.addAppender(newAppender);
        } else {
            addWarn("One and only one appender may be attached to AsyncAppender.");
            addWarn("Ignoring additional appender named [" + newAppender.getName() + "]");
        }
    }
```